# Click on first item in a GridView is not working

Tags: android, gridview

I have an activity which contains a `GridView`, each element of the `GridView` contains an `ImageView` and when the activity starts I want to perform a click on the first item's `ImageView`. I have tried several things which did not work:

```
gridView.performItemClick(gridView.getChildAt(0), 0, gridView.getAdapter().getItemId(0));
```

and with a `performClick()` directly.

However I think a found a way to do it by calling a function (`performEmptyClick()`) inside my custom `GridViewAdapter` which performs a click on the first item's `ImageView`.

My problem is that `performEmptyClick()` is called before the adapter's `getView()` is called (from debugging) and therefore the `onClickListener()` of the `ImageView` is not set up yet. Here is the code:

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.folderGridView);
folderViewAdapter = new FolderViewAdapter(this, R.layout.folder_item_layout, folderItems);
gridView.setAdapter(folderViewAdapter);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
noFolder = extras.getBoolean("noFolder");

if (noFolder) {
    folderViewAdapter.performEmptyClick();
}
```

Can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.folderGridView);
folderViewAdapter = new FolderViewAdapter(this, 
R.layout.folder_item_layout, folderItems);
gridView.setAdapter(folderViewAdapter);

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
noFolder = extras.getBoolean("noFolder");

if (noFolder) {
  gridView.getChildAt(0).performClick();
}
```